# I'm trying to compare two fastq file(paired reads),print line number n of another file

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, fastq

I'm trying to compare two fastq reads(paired reads) such that position(considering line number) of pattern match in file1.fastq is compared to file2.fastq. I want to print what lies on the same position or line number in file2.fastq. I'm trying to do this through awk.  Ex. If my pattern match lies in line number 200 in file1, I want to see what is there in line 200 in file 2. Any suggestion on this appreciated.

Comment: Sample input and sample output would be greatly helpful. As would your current attempt(s).

Comment: Not saying people here can't help, but a similar Q&A site [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) may give better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want this form:

```
awk '
    { getline line_2 < "file2" }
    /pattern/ { print FNR, line_2 }
' file1
```

Alternately, paste the files together first (assuming your shell is bash)

```
paste -d $'\1' file1 file2 | awk -F $'\1' '$1 ~ /pattern/ {print FNR, $2}'
```

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as the field delimiter, assuming that characters does not appear in your files.

Comment: As I understood it, he/she is looking for patterns in file1. And if he finds what he's looking for, he wants to see what's at that same position in file2. So something like `if(line_1~/pattern/) print line_2` would work here.

Comment: @Cabbie407 Yes! you are right. I'm looking for a pattern match in file1. I want to get a list of line numbers of the matches. Then, I want to find what is at the same line number in file2. I have thousands of line numbers from the match so if(line_1~/pattern/) print line_2 will not work

Comment: @glenn jackman that is a nice approach but I doesn't seem to be working. It just gave me line numbers and no content but i do see a content when I check for the first pattern match line in file 2. Is there another approach to this I can try.

Comment: You need to show some sample input and the desired output. Your wordy description is insufficient. Please edit your question to provide the requested data.

Comment: @glenn jackman It worked! turns out i just had a small glitch in pasting due to my zipped files. Thanks for the help. Plz ignore my niavete,ambiguous comments!

Answer (score 0):

My novice attempt so far

```
zcat file1.fastq.gz|awk '~/pattern/{print NR;}'>matches.csv

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next;}(FNR in a)' matches.csv file2.fastq.gz
```

Comment: I think you haven't understood what the solution from glenn jackman does. file1 and file2 are read simultaneously, in parallel. There's no need to save line numbers, because the actual line from file 2 is always right there, in memory. In the variable line_2. So if there's something found in file1 the corresponding line from file 2 can be printed directly. Or I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you have three files.  A pattern file and two data files.  You want to find the line numbers of the patterns in data file 1 and find the corresponding lines in data file 2.  You'll get more help if you can clarify it and perhaps provide input files and expected output.

awk to the rescue!

```
awk -F: -vOFS=: 'NR==FNR{lines[$1]=$0;next} FNR in lines{print lines[FNR],$0}' <(grep -nf pattern data1) data2
```

will print line number, pattern matched from data file 1, and corresponding line from data file 2.  For my made up files with quasi-random data I got.

```
1:s1265e:s1265e
2:s28629e:s28629e
3:s6630e:s6630e
4:s24530e:s24530e
5:s23216e:s23216e
6:s25985e:s25985e
```

Comment: I have just two files file1 and file2. In my attempt, i made a third file of pattern matches from file 1 and pipe it to file 2. I'm not sure if this is a wise way but I just tried it to see if it worked.